# Is It Possible to Declare a JS Object Conforms to Multiple Interfaces in Function Signature with FlowJS?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to apply the Swift-influenced style of Protocol-Oriented Development in JavaScript with FlowJS interfaces. Is it legal in JS to declare that an object conforms to multiple Flow-defined interfaces? I haven't seen anything online or in documentation that communicates the possibility of this which is why I'm asking.

It would look something like the following...

```
// IRegisterAPI.js
interface IRegisterAPI {
    register(): void
}

// ILogInAPI.js
interface ILogInAPI {
    logIn(): void
}

// logIn.js
type LogInInput = {
    username: string,
    password: string
}

type LogInCollaborators = {
    authService: IRegisterAPI, ILogInAPI // Is this possible right here?
}

const logIn = ({username, password}: LogInInput, {authService}: LogInCollaborators) => {
    // call both authService.register() and authService.logIn() in logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [Intersection Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/)

```
// IRegisterAPI.js
type IRegisterAPI = {
    register: () => void
}

// ILogInAPI.js
type ILogInAPI = {
    logIn: () => void
}

// logIn.js
type LogInInput = {
    username: string,
    password: string
}

type LogInCollaborators = {
    authService: IRegisterAPI & ILogInAPI
}


const logIn = ({username, password}: LogInInput, {authService}: LogInCollaborators) => {
    // call both authService.register() and authService.logIn() in logic
}
```

Interfaces [also exist](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/) in Flow but they are for classes. So in your case you have to declare class that implements interfaces and explicitly create an object of that class(I've simplified original code for better readability):

```
interface IRegisterAPI {
    register(): void
}

interface ILogInAPI {
    login(): void
}

class AuthServiceClass implements IRegisterAPI, ILogInAPI {
    login() {}

    register() {}
}


const API = (authService: AuthServiceClass) => {

}

// next is fine
API(new AuthServiceClass()); 
// next fails because object literal is not instance of AuthServiceClass class
API({login: () => {}, register: () => {}});
```